# operator overloading in a struct in cpp

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was reading   and I am confused in below operator overloading part,
here how we can sort without defining the comparator.

How is sorting taking Place over two structure without defining any comparator,how compiler get to know on what basis it has two sort?

When we are going to use when e1

suppose the default comparator of STL sort using something like this 
e1bool operator<(Edge const& other) inside struct.

```
struct Edge {
    int u, v, weight;
    bool operator<(Edge const& other) {
        return weight < other.weight;
    }
}; 
vector<Edge> edges;
sort(edges.begin(), edges.end());
```

Comment: This is really unclear you know? Please [edit] your question before it gets closed. Be sure to **actually ask a question**. Also, read [ask].

Comment: the question is still unclear. "how we can sort without defining the comparator." but you do define a comparator. As you correctly suppose, `sort` uses `operator<` as default. It reads as if you answer your own question

Comment: Are you asking how `std::sort` works?

Answer (score 0):

By default, [`std::sort()`](https://devdocs.io/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses `operator<()` as a comparator. This is why sorting works with your `Edge` struct.

If you wish to perform custom sorting, or your struct/class doesn't provide `operator<()`, then you would need to pass a comparator function object to `std::sort()`. For example, if we change your `Edge` struct to remove `operator<()`...

```
struct Edge {
    int u, v, weight;
}; 

void print_edges(const std::vector<Edge> &edges)
{
    for (Edge const &e : edges)
    {
        std::cout << e.weight << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Edge> edges { {4, 5, 9}, {1, 2, 3} };
    std::cout << "Unsorted:\n";
    print_edges(edges);

    std::sort(edges.begin(), edges.end(), [](Edge const &lhs, Edge const &rhs){
        return lhs.weight < rhs.weight;
    });

    std::cout << "Sorted:\n";
    print_edges(edges);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how  the sorting taking place in above algorithm I mean  you have defined your own comparator but they did something in structure?

Comment: @humblefool - I updated my answer to discuss how `std::sort()` works without a custom comparator at the start.